# Custom Task Runner vs gulp, grunt, Webpack, npm CLI scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

I'd like to reach out to other experienced web devs to get your opinion on how best to handle compiling/building a web app.

A bit of background.  I started a long long time ago bundling my apps using grunt with browserfy.  Mainly just the JS side to bundle dependencies.  and I was still using normal css and html.

Then Gulp seemed to be the popular task runner, so I switched to that for new projects.  I preferred Grunt, but it seemed like Gulp would take the prize for most used.

Then Webpack.  What a pain it was in the beginning.  Like we all know, it's not necessarily a task runner, more a bundler, but people use it to do things I don't think it was initially meant for.

Last, possibly in combination with Webpack, simple npm scripts calling command line tasks.

Eventually my setup became pretty complicated, just using Webpack wasn't cutting it, so I made my own custom javascript task runner, and still imported packages like Webpack, fs-extra, image magik, node-sass, etc.  Using the api's to do all the image optimization, file movement, i18n, etc.

Now, rather than wrap all these packages with my own custom task runner, why not just go back to grunt or gulp...  Btw, using just npm scripts and calling tasks from the command line is too generic, I need a bit more customization.

So now I'd like to know what you guys do.  Guys that have also made the rounds with various task runners, complicated Webpack setups, etc.  Do you: roll your own custom task runners, relay on just NPM scripts calling cli tasks, use a heavily nested Webpack script, grunt, gulp, ... something else?

To be honest, by now(2020) I figured gulp or grunt would have faded away, though that doesn't seem to be the case.  Maybe I'm in the minority with a custom task runner for a more complicated build (for simple builds, npm script cli processes) and I should go back to Gulp or Grunt...

I'd be grateful for your opinions regarding your method of choice for slightly complicated build processes.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I choose a tool, I generally have two primary considerations:

- How much time/effort/headache will the tool save me through the foreseeable future
- How much time/effort/headache will learning this tool require upfront

For complicated builds, Gulp saves me quite a bit of time/effort/headache, and requires very little upfront effort. It's a simple js tool, easy for anyone in the company to learn and use. As you know, it can do (just about) anything needed in terms of building a complicated project.

One factor I take into account in the "how much will the tool save me in future", especially in the fast-paced world of javascript, is how long I think the tool will be maintained by its owners. The Gulp team is offering Enterprise support, actively maintaining the project, there are over 1.2 million downloads weekly, so in my opinion I think they'll be around for awhile. Certainly long enough that we'll get more value out of the tool than sweat we put into learning it.

For complicated builds, in my experience much more upfront effort is required with Webpack. NPM scripts require more finagling for things that gulp abstracts well. In my simple upfront effort vs. longterm value calculation, Gulp wins the complicated build race.

Comment: Hello Kayakin, first, thank you very much for your response.  I think opinion questions like this don't get much feedback compared to more straightforward question like how to do x...

Next, in doing more research, I agree with you.  First, as you said, Gulp is popular and supported.  That was one of the main reasons I left it at first, moving to Webpack.  The later seemed to be all the rage and I thought that Gulp would decrease it popularity, the way Grunt was when Gulp started its ascension.  However, unlike those, Webpack wasn't a real alternative, more a bundler like Browserfy.

Comment: Last, my frustration and motivation first a custom task runner was really built around limitations of making Webpack do what I wanted (task runner stuff).

Now that I see Gulp IS still popular, why should I be reinventing the wheel still when an off the shelf product exists.  Rather the comparing my custom task runner to Webpack scripts, it should be compared to Gulp.  My setup is not likely too complicated for Gulp like it was for just Webpack.  

It's hit or miss trying to predict what tech tools will persist, though its important to re-eval and possibly pivot (back) over time.  Thanks!

Comment: @paultman yes when Webpack started to gain popularity, we too thought "hmm, we should take a look at this". And we did. It's often hard to decide when/how to make a tooling switch; for that decision, I just modify my decision-making questions a bit to "How much time/effort/headache will the tool save me through the foreseeable future *versus* the same question for the current tool we're using"